# 配列読み込みのためのコードを書いたのですが、エラーになります。

Tags: c

スペース区切りの整数の配列を読み込むコードを書きたいのですが、
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
というエラーになります。
以下のコードです。(nの入力の部分は省略していますが、
これは正しく行われていることを確認しています。)

```
void input_iarray(char* s,int* a,int n,int imax);
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 1000000100
int main(void){
    char* s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
    fgets(s,N,stdin);
// nの入力
    int* a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    input_iarray(s,a,n,sizeof(char)*N);
    return 0;
}
void input_iarray(char* s,int* a,int n,int imax){
    int aidx=0,i=0; 
    while(*(s+i)!=0 && i<imax){
        if (*(s+i)<48 || *(s+i)>57){i++;}
        else{
            int bidx=i;
            while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
                i++;
            }
            int t=0;
            for(int j=bidx;j<i;j++){
                t*=10;
                t+=*(s+j)-48;
            }
        *(a+aidx++)=t;
        }
    }
    if (aidx!=n)printf("n!=aidx\n");
}
```

Comment: 17行目のinput_iarray関数の第四引数はsizeof(char)*NではなくNとすべきことに気が付きましたが、そこを直してもやはり同じエラーになります。

Comment: コードはこれで全てでしょうか？そもそもコンパイルが通らない気がします。また、コメント欄で言及している 17 行目もコードと合わないです。

Comment: 「nの入力の部分は省略しています」とありますが、その変数`n`が`main()`の中(あるいはmainからアクセスできる場所)に存在していません。記事に書かれたソースコードで問題を再現出来ることを確認しましたか？ 質問記事を書く際の転記ミスと思われますが、それでは問題を再現する所にたどり着くことが出来ないのでは？ 入力処理は省略しても変数の宣言とダミーとなる典型的な値の設定は必要でしょう。また使っているPC,OS,コンパイラ,IDEの種類や版数などの情報も追記してください。

Comment: 解決しました。
cubickさん、kunifさん。コメントありがとうございます。
ごちゃごちゃして見にくいとよくないと思い、今回の問題には関係がない(と思った)部分を省略したコードを載せたのですが、確かにコードの全文がないと判断しづらいかもしれません。以後は実行を試したコードの全文を載せるようにします。
実際、今回のエラーの原因は省略した部分と絡んでいて、n,dの読み込み用のバッファをそのまま配列が入った文字列の読み込みに使ってしまったのが原因だったようです。
ぴーよさん、Delft Viewさん。ご解答有難うございます。ただ、今回入力を試したのは、n個だけしか数字が入っていないデータなので、これが今回のエラー原因ではなかったですが、n個以上のデータが入っているかもしれないデータを読む必要があることもあるかもしれないので、ご解答は参考になりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

再現できずエラーの原因は特定できなかったので御参考です。

いずれにせよ，確保したメモリー領域外へのアクセスは回避したいので，以下のような方法も考えられます。

- 入力文字列（`s`）から入力された数値（整数）の個数を得る（`input_icount()`）
- その結果（`n`）を基に配列（`a`）の領域を確保する
- 入力文字列（`s`）から配列（`a`）に数値を読み込む（`input_iarray()`）

記述例を下記に示します。

（追記）

ふたつの関数をひとつの関数（`int input_iarray(char *, int *, int)`）にまとめました。数値の個数を返すように変更し，2番目の引数に `NULL` を設定した場合は数値を配列へ読み込む処理をスキップするようにしました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 1000000

int input_iarray(char *, int *, int);

int main(void)
{
    char *s;
    int *a, n, i;

    if ((s = (char *)malloc(N)) == NULL)
        return 1;

    fgets(s, N, stdin);

    n = input_iarray(s, NULL, N);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);

    if ((a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n)) == NULL)
        return 1;

    input_iarray(s, a, N);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, a[i]);

    return 0;
}

int input_iarray(char *s, int *a, int imax)
{
    int aidx = 0, i = 0;
    int bidx, t, j;

    while (i < imax && s[i] != 0) {
        if (s[i] < 48 || 57 < s[i]) {
            i++;
        } else {
            bidx = i;
            while (i < imax && 48 <= s[i] && s[i] <= 57) {
                i++;
            }
            if (a == NULL) {
                aidx++;
                continue;
            }
            for (t = 0, j = bidx; j < i; j++) {
                t *= 10;
                t += s[j] - 48;
            }
            a[aidx++] = t;
        }
    }

    return aidx;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`input_iarray()`関数は文字列`s`に入ってる数字とその個数を数え、数字を`a`に、個数を`aidx`に記録し、`aidx`と`n`を比べる関数ですね。一応コメント等を読んでコードを次のように書き直してみました。

```c
void input_iarray(char* s,int* a,int n,int imax);
#pragma warning(disable:4996) // scanf()を使うため
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 1000000100
int main()
{
    char* s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
    if(!s)return -1; // sの例外処理
    fgets(s,N,stdin);
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n); // nの入力
    int* a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    if(!a) // aの例外処理
    {
        free(s);
        return -1;
    }
    input_iarray(s,a,n,N);
    free(s),free(a);
    return 0;
}
void input_iarray(char* s,int* a,int n,int imax){
    int aidx=0,i=0; 
    while(*(s+i)!=0 && i<imax){
        if (*(s+i)<48 || *(s+i)>57){i++;}
        else{ // 数字
            int bidx=i;
            while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
                i++;
            }
            int t=0;
            for(int j=bidx;j<i;j++){
                t*=10;
                t+=*(s+j)-48;
            }
        *(a+aidx++)=t;
        }
    }
    if (aidx!=n)printf("n!=aidx\n");
}
```

いまのエラー`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`は、配列等の範囲外の部分へのアクセスをするとき発生します。

たとえ、入力が`s="---555-23-4--12---44-"`, `n=3`のときは、
`a`は大きさ`sizeof(int)*3`のメモリしか確保してないのに
関数`input_iarray()`が`555, 23, 4, 12, 44`をそれぞれ`a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]`にアクセスして記録しようとします。
`aidx`が`3`になって`a+aidx`にアクセスするとき問題になります。

したがって、`sに入ってる数字の個数 > n`のときそのエラーが出ると思います。
`a`に`s`のすべての数字を記録しなくてもいいなら`input_iarray()`の`else{}`を次のように改変するとエラーが出ないと思います。

```c
else{ // 数字
    int bidx=i;
    while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
        i++;
    }
    if(n>=aidx) // aが満杯なら
    {
        aidx++; // a+aidxにアクセスせずにaidx++
        continue;
    }
    int t=0;
    for(int j=bidx;j<i;j++){
        t*=10;
        t+=*(s+j)-48;
    }
    *(a+aidx++)=t;
}
```

`a`に`s`のすべての数字を記録したいときは`realloc()`関数で確保したいメモリを増やす必要があると思います。